# Swing - change LayoutManager : two components per line

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I'm creating a Java application and currently I use this layout manager :

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

/**
 * @author Pasban
 */

public class VerticalLayout implements LayoutManager {

    public final static int CENTER = 0;
    public final static int RIGHT = 1;
    public final static int LEFT = 2;
    public final static int BOTH = 3;
    public final static int TOP = 1;
    public final static int BOTTOM = 2;
    private int vgap;
    private int alignment;
    private int anchor;

    public VerticalLayout() {
        this(5, CENTER, TOP);
    }

    public VerticalLayout(int vgap) {
        this(vgap, CENTER, TOP);
    }

    public VerticalLayout(int vgap, int alignment) {
        this(vgap, alignment, TOP);
    }

    public VerticalLayout(int vgap, int alignment, int anchor) {
        this.vgap = vgap;
        this.alignment = alignment;
        this.anchor = anchor;
    }

    private Dimension layoutSize(Container parent, boolean minimum) {
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
        Dimension d;
        synchronized (parent.getTreeLock()) {
            int n = parent.getComponentCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                if (c.isVisible()) {
                    d = minimum ? c.getMinimumSize() : c.getPreferredSize();
                    dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, d.width);
                    dim.height += d.height;
                    if (i > 0) {
                        dim.height += vgap;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
        dim.width += insets.left + insets.right;
        dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vgap + vgap;
        return dim;
    }

    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
        synchronized (parent.getTreeLock()) {
            int n = parent.getComponentCount();
            Dimension pd = parent.getSize();
            int y = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                if (c.isVisible()) {
                    y += d.height + vgap;
                }
            }
            y -= vgap;
            if (anchor == TOP) {
                y = insets.top;
            } else if (anchor == CENTER) {
                y = (pd.height - y) / 2;
            } else {
                y = pd.height - y - insets.bottom;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                Component c = parent.getComponent(i);
                Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
                if (!c.isVisible()) {
                    continue;
                }
                int x = 1;
                int wid = pd.width - 3;
                c.setBounds(x, y, wid, d.height);
                y += d.height + vgap;
            }
        }
    }

    public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        return layoutSize(parent, false);
    }

    public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
        return layoutSize(parent, false);
    }

    public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
    }

    public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[vgap=" + vgap + " align=" + alignment + " anchor=" + anchor + "]";
    }
}
```

Example of use (the components are vertically aligned) :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGtbz.png]

As you can see, each component is on one line. But, I would like some components to be two on one line.

For example, JButtons will be on one line, just like it is now. Same thing for JTextAreas.

But, I would like to have the JLabels and the JTextFields to be on the same line. And the same for the JLabels and the JComboBoxs, on the same line.

And I don't really know how to do it. Could someone explain me ? :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is really difficult to understand exactly why are you creating a Layout of your own?
Have a look at `GridBagLayout`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

The use-cases you are explaining can be easily met by using GridBagLayout.

Comment: well, GridBagLayout is kind of complex to use, and instead of configuring a lot of things I would like to make it 'automatic' (1 or 2 lines of code)

Comment: Again, let me tell you that spending a little more time on GrigBagLayout will do a world of good. In case you still want to implement your own Layout Manager, do it by extending the GridBagLayout instead. Use a two column GridBagLayout. For components that are supposed to take a full row, keep their grid width to be 2. For others, add them with a grid width of 1. What you are trying to do is far too complex, than what GridBagLayout can do for you - all the configurations you are trying to avoid, are still easier than writing truckload of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two components on each line then use the standard `GridLayout`.

You can force the components to wrap by specifying that you only want two columns of components:

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0, 2);
JPanel panel = new JPanel( layout );
```

Comment: I've tried GridLayout, but the components fill the whole case and it's ugly. Is it a way to fix this ?

Comment: @PYRRH4, `but the components fill the whole case` - don't know what that means.

Comment: A simple example (you can see that the buttons are very, big) : http://imgur.com/a/zRZ5Y

Comment: @PYRRH4, so add the panel to the frame using BorderLayout.PAGE_START instead of BorderLayout.CENTER. And you should be using frame.pack(). Post a proper [mcve] if you need more help because that picture is different than the first picture so you keep changing the requirements.